# In a Springboot Maven project, how to reference from another Jar?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

I have a SpringBoot Maven project. I am dependent on another set of libraries. Currently am pointing to their repository path , downloading it to .m2 repository and using.

But the repository website is not reliable. **SO I wanted to package the dependent libraries as part of JAR in the resources folder.
After putting the jars in resource folder. How can I get references of the Types/libraries ?**

Currently:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.23.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>www.dcm4che.org</id>
            <name>dcm4che Repository</name>
            <url>https://www.dcm4che.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Where have you received them from?

Comment: the libraries are hosted in : https://www.dcm4che.org/maven2 but the site went down currently. I need to avoid such mishaps by simply packaging the dependencies in resources folder.

Comment: Don't put dependencies into the resources folder. Use your own repository manager instead.

Comment: that's an option but  i don't have a repository to point to currently , hence the packaging inside the resource folder itself

Comment: I strongly recommend to setup a repository manager exactly for such cases as suggested by J Fabian Meier...You can upload the artifacts there an in Maven you can go the default way...Apart from that the resource folder is absolute wrong because the resource folder will being copied during a build of a project into `target/classes` which is wrong...so you should consider using a different directory and configure a file repository via `file://${project.basedir}` But be careful for different platforms (like Windows) it might fail....

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your libraries in a single folder either in your project or in some folder in your local. You can then add them to your maven POM.

Lets say you put all your jars in a folder called `libs` in your base project directory. You can then add something similar to the below in your maven POM.

```
<groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${basedir}/libs/my-jar-name.jar</systemPath>
```

You need to use the scope `system`. Excerpt from Maven website,

> Scope : system  - This scope is similar to provided except that you
> have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is
> always available and is not looked up in a repository.

[Maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

If you read further, it also mentions that this has been deprecated. So, its a nice quickfix or a hack but then the best thing would be to set up a repository manager as suggested by others.